# Using dword value as an operand to ASM jmp

Tags: windows, wdk, endianness

I'm playing with some runtime function patching but I have a problem with the endiannes when writing memory address values. So what I have:

```
 char buf[] = \xE9\xDE\xAD\xBE\xEF
```

At runtime I have to fixup the 0xDEADBEEF to point to the actual address - here is my function to do this:

```
void FixJMPAddress(BYTE *jump, BYTE *newRoutine) {

  DWORD address;
  DWORD *dwPtr;

  address = (DWORD)newRoutine;
  dwPtr = (DWORD *)&(jump[1]);
  *dwPtr = address;

}
```

It is invoked like that:

```
  FixJMPAddress(buf, &Something);
```

Unfortunately when disassembling the end result I get:

```
   E9 60 DA 47 93
```

instead of

```
   E9 93 47 DA 60
```

So this is due to the fact that x86 is little-endian but is there a way in which I can cope with is automatically without having to write a function which essentially reverses the byteorder of the input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with little-endian. Your code assumes that the operand is stored in the same endianess as the architecture it's run on. That should be fine as long as your code runs on x86.

The real problem is that jmp uses a *relative* offset, not an absolute one.
To calculate the jmp destination:

```
dest = address_of_jmp + operand + sizeof(jmp_instruction)
```

Assuming `BYTE* jump` points to the actual instruction that will be executed, it should be:

```
LONG delta = address - (DWORD)jump - 5;
*(LONG*)(jump+1) = delta;
```